# How to set handler for GST_ERROR gstreamer debug messages in Win32 Windows application?

Tags: gstreamer

I am testing gstreamer in a Win32 Windows application (and not in a console application). I like to grab and display "gstreamer"'s debug and error messages (which are normally printed in a win32 console application) in my Win32 Windows application too. I can't see them in Win32 Windows application where I have my own main window and several child windows (and not the command prompt). Using

```
g_log_set_handler( G_LOG_DOMAIN, G_LOG_LEVEL_MASK | G_LOG_FLAG_FATAL| G_LOG_FLAG_RECURSION, MyfGstGenLogHandle, NULL );
```

only grabs "application" domain log messages in my "MyfGstGenLogHandle" function; meaning it only grabs e.g. where I myself used a g_debug( ... ) command in my own code. I tried the following commands to grab and display "gstreamer"'s debug and error messages (e.g. those are generated while playbin is trying to play a media):

```
g_log_set_default_handler( MyfGstGenLogHandle, NULL );
g_log_set_handler( G_LOG_DOMAIN     , (GLogLevelFlags) ( G_LOG_LEVEL_MASK | G_LOG_FLAG_FATAL| G_LOG_FLAG_RECURSION ), MyfGstGenLogHandle, NULL );
g_log_set_handler( NULL             , (GLogLevelFlags) ( G_LOG_LEVEL_MASK | G_LOG_FLAG_FATAL| G_LOG_FLAG_RECURSION ), MyfGstGenLogHandle, NULL );
g_log_set_handler( "GStreamer"      , (GLogLevelFlags) ( G_LOG_LEVEL_MASK | G_LOG_FLAG_FATAL| G_LOG_FLAG_RECURSION ), MyfGstGenLogHandle, NULL );
g_log_set_handler( "GLib-GObject"   , (GLogLevelFlags) ( G_LOG_LEVEL_MASK | G_LOG_FLAG_FATAL| G_LOG_FLAG_RECURSION ), MyfGstGenLogHandle, NULL );
g_log_set_handler( "GLib"           , (GLogLevelFlags) ( G_LOG_LEVEL_MASK | G_LOG_FLAG_FATAL| G_LOG_FLAG_RECURSION ), MyfGstGenLogHandle, NULL );
g_log_set_handler( "GModule"        , (GLogLevelFlags) ( G_LOG_LEVEL_MASK | G_LOG_FLAG_FATAL| G_LOG_FLAG_RECURSION ), MyfGstGenLogHandle, NULL );
g_log_set_handler( "GThread"        , (GLogLevelFlags) ( G_LOG_LEVEL_MASK | G_LOG_FLAG_FATAL| G_LOG_FLAG_RECURSION ), MyfGstGenLogHandle, NULL );
g_log_set_handler( "Gnt"            , (GLogLevelFlags) ( G_LOG_LEVEL_MASK | G_LOG_FLAG_FATAL| G_LOG_FLAG_RECURSION ), MyfGstGenLogHandle, NULL );
g_log_set_handler( "stderr"         , (GLogLevelFlags) ( G_LOG_LEVEL_MASK | G_LOG_FLAG_FATAL| G_LOG_FLAG_RECURSION ), MyfGstGenLogHandle, NULL );
g_log_set_handler( "stdout"         , (GLogLevelFlags) ( G_LOG_LEVEL_MASK | G_LOG_FLAG_FATAL| G_LOG_FLAG_RECURSION ), MyfGstGenLogHandle, NULL );
g_log_set_handler( "Gtk"            , (GLogLevelFlags) ( G_LOG_LEVEL_MASK | G_LOG_FLAG_FATAL| G_LOG_FLAG_RECURSION ), MyfGstGenLogHandle, NULL );
g_log_set_handler( "Gdk"            , (GLogLevelFlags) ( G_LOG_LEVEL_MASK | G_LOG_FLAG_FATAL| G_LOG_FLAG_RECURSION ), MyfGstGenLogHandle, NULL );
```

So far none of those tries helped me to grab gstreamer debug messages in Win32 Windows application, while the debug messages without using g_log_set_handler are normally printed in command prompt if I write the code in a Win32 console application. Is there any way to resolve this issue? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GStreamer has a different API for redirecting the log, it's named [gst_debug_add_log_function](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gstreamer-GstInfo.html#gst-debug-add-log-function).

As reference, you can use the [code](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/sdk/cerbero/tree/data/ndk-build/gstreamer_android-1.0.c.in#n364) we use in android to redirect GLib and GStreamer log to Android's logcat.